# head children missing in responseXML when trying to append to document

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, salesforce, visualforce

I have a rather simple requirement that I'm trying to implement:

1. Construct a XMLHttpRequest to load another page
2. Iterate through whatever is found in the `head` element in the other page
3. For each element found, append it to the `head` element in the current (calling) page

What I'm finding to be very odd and confusing is that some expected elements in the other page's `head` are **missing**. But as soon as I remove the single line of code that appends each found element to the calling page, all child elements in the other page's `head` magically appear.

For example, let's say the other page should have 2 `meta` elements, 3 `link` elements and 4 `script` elements. For some reason my XMLHttpRequest object's `responseXML` comes back having only 1 `meta` element, 1 `link` element and 3 `script` elements.

Below is the line of code that I really want to execute. But when I have it in the HTML source, some `head` children in `responseXML` go missing. You can see it in action on **[this bin](http://jsbin.com/niyeko/1)** or [this Visualforce page](https://00dj0000001ntu1eae-sites.secure.force.com/PublicWonderXMLHttpRequest).

```
head.appendChild(header.head.children[i]);
```

Below shows the same code commented out. When I do this, the missing children reappear. You can see it in action on **[this bin](http://jsbin.com/yapibi/1)** or [this Visualforce page](https://00dj0000001ntu1eae-sites.secure.force.com/PublicWonderXMLHttpRequest).

```
//head.appendChild(header.head.children[i]);
```

**What is causing the child elements to disappear?** If you open the JavaScript console (Chrome) or Web Console (Firefox), you can very clearly see the difference from loading the two pages above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still curious of the answer to the real question of *why* this happens. I've got a few thoughts, but this first: change your merge code to the following snippet.

```
  Communities.mergeHeader = function(header) {
    console.log("header: %o", header);

    var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
    head.innerHTML = header.head.outerHTML;
  };
```

I will follow up with the thoughts on why.

## follow-up

## [DEMO](http://codepen.io/presstep/pen/a385456d87e7f2c084dc338c1d885c09/?editors=001)

ok. got totally side-tracked. the reason that you're seeing those nodes "disappear" is because you are literally displacing them:

**js**
here we do our moving code

```
var list = document.getElementById('list'),
    btn = document.getElementById('btn');

document.head.appendChild(list);
```

**html** before

```
<ul id='list'>
  <li>Have</li>
  <li>you</li>
  <li>ever</li>
  <li>needed</li>
  <li>to</li>
  <li>keep</li>
  <li>a</li>
  <li>list</li>
  <li>in</li>
  <li>your</li>
  <li>head?</li>
</ul>

<p>Now you can:
  <button id='btn'>List -> Head</button>
</p>
```

**html2** after

**head element**

after move you can see that the body is missing the list.

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex">
    <link rel="canonical" href="http://codepen.io/presstep/pen/a385456d87e7f2c084dc338c1d885c09/?editors=101">
    <style class="cp-pen-styles">
        body {
          font: 300 25px/1 sans-serif;
        }
        ul {
          list-style-type: square;
        }
        p {
          font-size: 14px;
        }
    </style>
    <ul id="list">
        <li>Have</li>
        <li>you</li>
        <li>ever</li>
        <li>needed</li>
        <li>to</li>
        <li>keep</li>
        <li>a</li>
        <li>list</li>
        <li>in</li>
        <li>your</li>
        <li>head?</li>
    </ul>
</head>
<body>
  <p>Now you can:
    <button id='btn'>List -> Head</button>
  </p>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for solving this mystery, Todd. I changed the code to `head.appendChild(header.head.children[i].cloneNode());` and the logic appears to be working correctly now. [`Node.cloneNode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.cloneNode) creates a new element, so that when it's appended it doesn't get removed from anything. I found the official documentation on [`Node.appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.appendChild) and it corroborates what you identified.

Comment: np! anytime; always glad to help. And I almost mentioned clone node, but totally forgot. lol. got more wrapped up in copying and pasting code pen.